# nginx php-fpm configuration hitting children limit

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I'm having this problem with nginx + php7.0-fpm.

Testing is done on a pure php server with no other services installed.

I'm getting the following warning.

```
WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 35 total children
```

And it slows the server down greatly.

I'm using `AWS t2.medium instance` - 2vCPU and 4GB RAM.

My `php7.0-fpm/www.conf` set up looks like

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 500
```

I have a laravel application that I'm using to test which simply replies `{"m":"OK"}` to requests.

I tested that using `apache2-utils`

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 https://mytestserver.com/
```

Response from `ab` test -> https://ghostbin.com/paste/528tw

And I watch the CPU usage using `htop`.

The two CPU usages hit 100% quickly during `ab` test. However, Memory usage is only `400MB`.

Why is it using CPU too much? What do I do to make getting WARNING from php-fpm?

What am I doing wrong? Please guide me through.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you shouldnt spawn that much more children than cpu cores. you only have 2 virtual cores, I would only spawn 2 child servers.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, which one from pm. is referring to child servers?

Comment: `nginx` is much faster when it comes to accepting requests than PHP is in processing them. That means `nginx` "feeds" php with too many requests and `fpm` can't handle it in timely manner, it's children are busy and you get that warning. You can't fix it, because you hit the CPU limit - or, if you will, that's as fast as PHP will "go" at your server. When this scenario happens, that web server is so much faster, then we start using multiple servers with `php-fpm` and nginx can load balance between them. Raising any of those config variables won't do anything, you're out of CPU cores and power.

Comment: Most guides I read now are doing a way too simple calculation like "available memory / average PHP usage = amount of max children" - the problem is, this does not count the amount of CPU usage. You should use way less max children, **like 2 - 4 is enough** for hundreds of users on your website and it won't suck your **virtual** cpu cores to the outer limit.

Comment: @Mjh, Thanks. So, I will just have to ignore the WARNING I guess? But does my config make sense considering I have 2vCPU and 4GB RAM?

Comment: It does definitely not make sense to spawn up to 50 concurrent threads/forks on only 2 virtual cpu cores. In the worst case, it will block your SSH connection forever and you can't connect to the server anymore.

Comment: If you get that warning in *production*, that means you're having a busy period on your site and PHP is telling you to do something to serve everything, such as get another server with `php-fpm`. Since you did this for testing - I'd say it's safe to ignore for now, but to implement some sort of a warning that can let you know to react. Like Dan wrote, it doesn't make sense to spawn more processes as it won't help, it will do the opposite. Amazon has autoscaling service that you can use to increase the number of php processing nodes. You can research it and keep an open mind about this matter.

Comment: @Mjh Thanks. I'm now trying to understand the messages from `ab`. It says `Requests per second:    91.21 [#/sec] (mean)`. Does it mean my 2vCPU, 4GB RAM machine can only handle 100 requests/s at max? It's disappointing.

Comment: 2 vCPU is like a RaspberryPi dude, what do you expect? 90 request per second is fast for this little guy.

Comment: I would suggest using [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) over ab. Another thing that you have to take into account is that you shouldn't run `ab` from the same server you're testing as it's going to occupy CPU power which is already divided between nginx and php, so it's likely you're seeing wrong results. ests I ran on awsmedium showed that nginx can handle about 5k requests per second and PHP 7.1 could handle around 150 per core. I ran the test with 2 servers, one for nginx and the other one for fpm. Like Dan said, computer you're using is actually not that fast, so 100 per second isn't bad.

Comment: @Mjh, I'm running `ab` over another server. I'm going to try with `wrk` now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not only take in account the memory usage of PHP but also the concurrent CPU usage.

If you have too many child servers, it will only make things worse and slower and PHP can't handle any more of the requests, it can totally block everything.

Your server has a little too much memory for only 2 vCPUs, or the other way, it should have more CPU to fit to the amount of memory.

This is more appropriate for 2 virtual cpu cores:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 4
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_requests = 500
```

Also when you do 50 concurrent requests with Apache's Benchmark tool, it is totally normal for only 2 vCPU server to be very slow. Benchmarks should be ran from a different computer.

Keep in mind that the basic OS and your webserver (nginx) also needs some CPU usage.

Your AWS server has about the same power as a RaspberryPi with a little more memory.

Useful comment from [Mjh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133682/mjh):

> 100 requests a second isn't bad, if you get to a point where you have
>   that much - that's a great problem to have. Dropping SSL in favor for
>   requests per seconds might not be the best thing to do at this point.
>   Of course, I don't know anything about your site and what you use it
>   for, or whether SSL is needed or not, but having SSL does have an
>   impact on your google ranking. It's always min-maxing, and in case of
>   SSL, if I were you, I'd keep it.

Comment: Now I get the following WARNING `[10-Jan-2017 15:30:39] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (4), consider raising it`. And according to `ab`, it can only process 80 requests/sec? Is it normal for a 2vCPU and 4GB RAM machine? The app server is simply reply `{"m":"OK"}` with no logic.

Comment: You need to play arround with these numbers, but keep them between 1 and 5. On production, you don't want your server to be at 100% full cpu usage all the time. You want it to be arround 60%, so it can handle peaks and won't block your SSH access.

Comment: oh wow, aws `t2.medium` is pretty shit and it costs $45/month. fml.

Comment: @moeseth 99 is pretty low, I'm getting more on a micro one. Did you turn opcache on?

Comment: @Mjh, after testing, SSL seems to be the problem. With http:// I could serve much more.

Comment: Maybe it's better if you enable VPN between your hosts and not use https instead and still be secure. Or have a one-time-pad for encryption.

Comment: I'm sorry for polluting your answer Dan, but just one thing I'd highlight @moeseth - 100 requests a second isn't bad, if you get to a point where you have that much - that's a great problem to have. Dropping SSL in favor for requests per seconds might not be the best thing to do at this point. Of course, I don't know anything about your site and what you use it for, or whether SSL is needed or not, but having SSL does have an impact on your google ranking. It's always min-maxing, and in case of SSL, if I were you, I'd keep it.

Comment: @Mjh no problem. This is a good point. On a testing machine probably https isn't that important, but on production and public machines, you maybe should keep it enabled. Do you want me to put this into the answer?

Comment: @DanFromGermany, you should. Currently, I just need to handle 30 requests/s on average. So I bet this works fine on my $45/month machine.

Comment: @moseth I have a low budget server from server4you.de it costs $30 and has 8 physical cores with 32 GB RAM on 2 TB SSD. AWS is too expensive for many use cases.

Comment: Just to chip in once more - I got a free tier AWS, which costs around $5.45 a month (odd definition of free), it's a micro instance and it averages at ~40 requests per second (nginx 1.10, http2, letsencrypt ssl certificate and php 7.1). I agree that aws is expensive for certain use cases, but it brings value if you require additional services - autoscaling, changing instance size, adding more instances etc. As usual, everything boils down to the right tool for the job. Two micro instances might be cheaper than one medium, so one can be used for nginx and the other one for php-fpm.